# flutter how to check if a String contains at least one String from a list of Strings

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to check if the value that the user enters in a TextFormField contains at least one String in another given String.

As an example, if the given String value is `0123456789` and if the user enters `Ab3` in the TextFormField, how to check if the user entered value contains at least one String in the given String?

```
 String allowedChar = "0123456789";
 final split = allowedChar.split('');
```

I tried splitting the given value like this and checked if the `textEditingController.text` contains the value for each splitted value of `allowedChar`.

```
if (_value.isNotEmpty &&
  textEditingController.text.contains(c)) {
    _areAlwdCharsTyped = true;
} else if (!textEditingController.text.contains(c)) {
    _areAlwdCharsTyped = false;
}
```

But `_areAlwdCharsTyped` always returns false. Could I know a way to achieve this please? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

```
void main() {
  const text = 'Ab3';
  var match = RegExp(r'\d').hasMatch(text);
  
  print(match);
}
```

Result

```
true
```

Comment: Thank you for taking time to answer my question, sir. But the thing is `allowedChar` can change, since it's coming from an api call. Even though the `allowedChar` value is `0123456789` at the time, it could change to something else.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're close. You can iteratively check whether the input string contains any of the chars in allowedChars.

```
void main() {
 String allowedChar = "0123456789";
 final split = allowedChar.split('');
 final str = 'AB3';
 final str2 = 'AB';
  
 print(split.fold<bool>(false, (prev, element) => str.contains(element) || prev)); // true
 print(split.fold<bool>(false, (prev, element) => str2.contains(element) || prev)); // false
}
```